# Importing html file inside html code on google app script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have made an html file called navBar.html

```
    <nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown" style= "background-color: #191970" >
        <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Page' target="_top" id="Home" class="dropbtn">Home</a>
        <div class ="dropdown-content">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"style= "background-color: #191970">
          <a href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyyYKI6fGf_LnRA8jPDa1QTJwUGqrG34lTDmHyugMHFZ4LYcWF4OBxjxa6BPtRyw-gj/exec" target="_top" id="Game" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
          <div class ="dropdown-content">
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown" style= "background-color: #191970" >
        <a href="#"  class="dropbtn">Cipher</a>
        <div class ="dropdown-content">
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Caesar_Cipher' target="_top" id="Caesar_Cipher" name="Caesar_Cipher"> Caesar_Cipher </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Simple_Substitution_Cipher' target="_top" id="Simple_Substitution_Cipher" name="Simple_Substitution_Cipher"> Simple_Substitution_Cipher </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Playfair_Cipher' target="_top" id="Playfair_Cipher" name="Playfair_Cipher"> Playfair_Cipher </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Vigenere_Cipher' target="_top" id="Vigenere_Cipher" name="Vigenere_Cipher"> Vigenere_Cipher </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=One_Time_Pad' target="_top" id="One_Time_Pad" name="One_Time_Pad"> One_Time_Pad </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Transposition_Cipher' target="_top" id="Transposition_Cipher" name="Transposition_Cipher"> Transposition Cipher </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Feistel_Block_Cipher' target="_top" id="Feistel_Block_Cipher" name="Feistel_Block_Cipher"> Feistel_Block_Cipher </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    <li class="dropdown" style= "background-color: #191970" >
        <a href="#"  class="dropbtn">Encryptions</a>
        <div class ="dropdown-content">
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=DES' target="_top" id="DES" name="DES"> DES </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=AES' target="_top" id="AES" name="AES"> AES </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=RSA' target="_top" id="RSA" name="RSA"> RSA </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=ElGamal_Cryptosystem' target="_top" id="ElGamal_Cryptosystem" name="ElGamal_Cryptosystem"> ElGamal_Cryptosystem </a>
          <?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=Triple_DES' target="_top" id="Triple_DES" name="Triple_DES"> Triple_DES </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I am trying to reuse this code in several different pages by importing it. For example, in my index.html file, instead of copying and pasting the navbar, I want to import it into the body. I tried using jquery load function, html5 import, and even w3.js and all were not able to import my html code. I am using an unbound script, with code.gs, navBar.html and index.html. Any recommendations or ideas on how to proceed with reusing navbar.html inside index.html with google script web pages.

Comment: Have you tried this method? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: yes I did, and it produced a 404 error when getting navBar.html

Comment: Do you get the same error with the other ways you tried?

Comment: They all give a 404 error.

Comment: I believe, but not 100% sure about this, that google app script does not treat the files as if they are on a server. It seems as if they are treated as local files. Of the above attempts mentioned, html5 import and w3.js w3-include-html have both worked for me in the past but this my first time attempting it on google app script. And thats the only reason i can think of as why they didnt work this time

Comment: Yeah that was my thought. It may be an inherit limitation. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. To be honest, I did not expect anyone to really have a solution but figured it was worth a shot. I mean its a free web server basically so limitations are expected.

Comment: No worries at all. I always like to help if possible, and it's almost impossible for someone to include everything they've tried, so I always assume they may not have. Good luck on your coding journey! :)

Comment: Hi there @savasgrk! In order to look for a workaround for you, could you explain what your end goal is?

Comment: Sure, So I am going to be constantly adding new hyperlinks/tabs on the navbar, but the navbar is going to be on, currently, 8 pages and every time I add to the navbar, I am going to be adding a new page which I want the navbar to be on. This means i need to go back and manually update every page. Currently 8 to 15 pages i don't mind updating but its eventually going to get hectic and time consuming to update each page manually. I want to be able to update the navbar.html, and it'll update every other page with the new navbar.

Answer (score 0):

After evaluating your situation I came with a simple fix. I strongly recommend you to implement [templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#code.gs_6). With them you can dynamic HTMLs with the minimal effort. Please follow the guide and its examples. Feel free to write back if you find any issue with it.